# Block Wordpress from resizing gifs automatically

Tags: wordpress, gif, responsive-images

A site I maintain only displays .gifs when they're animated, all non-animated images are .pngs or .jpgs 100% of the time.

Is there a hook that I can use to block Wordpress from resizing .gifs when Wordpress automatically resizes images for responsive display?

I'm using Wordpress 4.4.1.